# Can I get rid of these eval?

Tags: macros, clojure, eval

I'd like to build a list of operations to execute in a Redis pipeline. I was using [accession](https://github.com/abedra/accession) since it's much simpler than [carmine](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine), but now I need connection pooling (missing from accession) and thus I'm looking at carmine again (it seems the go-to and most complete clojure library for redis)

I managed to get this working:

```
; require [taoensso.carmine :as redis]
(defn execute1 [request] (redis/wcar {} (eval request)))
(defmacro execute [body] `(redis/wcar {} ~@(eval body)))

(def get1 `(redis/get 1))
(execute1 get1)
(execute [get1])
```

but given that I'll build **vectors of thousands of elements**, I'm a bit worried about the possible performance hit of `eval` (besides the fact that I've been taught to always avoid eval if possible). I reckon that `defmacro` instead is/can be evaluated at macro-expansion time, which might be earlier (during AOT compilation?) and without using eval.

Is there anything that I can do? should I move to a different library?
(I had a look at carmine's source code: my pain is only due to a small convenience for the author: a `*context*` used to avoid passing around a couple extra argument: getting rid of it should be simple enough, but I'm not invested enough in it... I might as well decide to move to another data store in the future)

**edit**: I've been asked to write an example of what I think is the boilerplate that I'd prefer to avoid writing in my actual code, so: (the following is untested, it's just a POC)

```
(defn hset [id key val]
  #(redis/hset id key val))

(defn hsetnx [id key val]
  #(redis/hsetnx id key val))

(defn hincrby [id key increment]
  #(redis/hincrby id key increment))

(defn hgetall [id key]
  #(redis/hgetall id key))

(defn sadd [id el]
  #(redis/sadd id el))

(defn scard [id]
  #(redis/scard id))

(defn smembers [id]
  #(redis/smembers id))

(defmacro execute [forms]
  `(redis/wcar {} ~@(map apply forms)))

; end boilerplate

(defn munge-element [[a b c]]
  (conj
    (mapcat #(hincrby a :whatever %) b)
    (sadd c b)
    (hsetnx a c))

(defn flush-queue! [queue_]
  (execute queue_)
  [])

(defn receive [item]
  (if (< (count @queue) 2000)
    (swap! queue conj (munge-element item))
    (swap! queue flush-queue!)))
```

Obviously, I could write something like this, but if this was truly the inteneded way to use carmine, these curried functions would be provided along (or instead of) the normal ones. Also a lot of lines could be shaved off by constructing up the `def`s with syntax quoting, but this is accidental complexity, not inherent the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code does not differ very much from yours:

```
(defmacro execute [& forms]
   `(redis/wcar {} ~@forms))

(defn get1 []
  (redis/get 1))

(execute (get1) (get1) ...)
```

This is basically how carmine *should* be used (following [this suggestion](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine#connections) in the README). If it doesn't suit your needs, could you clarify why?

---

After the question was edited to present more clearly what should be accomplished I think I have a solution for you. You're trying to create a list of statements to be executed at some specific time in the future. To achieve this you're wrapping each statement inside a function and I agree, that's a lot of boilerplate.

But unnecessary. You can get the same result by having a macro that automatically creates thunks for you:

```
(defmacro statements [& forms]
  `(vector
     ~@(for [f forms]
         `(fn [] ~f))))
```

Now, whatever you pass to this macro will result in a vector of zero-parameter functions that can be evaluated e.g. using:

```
(defn execute-statements [fns]
   (redis/wcar {} (mapv #(%) fns))
```

And your example turns into something along the lines of:

```
(defn munge-element [[a b c]]
  (statements
    (mapcat #(redis/hincrby a :whatever %) b)
    (redis/sadd c b)
    (redis/hsetnx a c))

(defn flush-queue! [queue_]
  (mapv execute-statements queue_)
  [])
```

**Edit:** This executes every batch in its own pipeline. If you want to do it in a single one, use `concat` instead of `conj` to build up your queue (in `receive`) and `(execute-statements queue_)` instead of `(mapv execute-statements queue_)`.

**Note:** IIRC correctly, this:

```
(redis/wcar {} a [b c]])
```

returns the same result as this:

```
(redis/wcar {} a b c)
```

I.e., carmine collects the results somewhere and always returns a vector for all of them. Even if not, I think you can still avoid your dreaded boilerplate by just tweaking the stuff presented here a little bit.

Comment: It's very cumbersome to use it like that: I'd have to either: 1) create a curried function for each and every redis function that I'm using (right now I have in my code hset, hsetnx, hincrby, hgetall, sadd, dbsize, scard, smembers, info... this would amount to a lot of boilerplate) or 2) wrap each and every invocation of a redis command in `partial`

Comment: Not to mention that your execute has a different API: to get it into a slightly more useful form, I'd have to use something like... `(defmacro execute [forms] \`(redis/wcar {} ~@(map apply forms)))` but once I did that, it might actually not be worse than my current solution (having to syntax quote every invokation of any redis command)

Comment: First, to get the same function signature as your `execute`, just leave out the `&` in the parameter list. It will then accept any seq of commands. Second, how is there a lot of boilerplate involved? If you don't want `defn` and the parameter list `[]`, just use something like `(def get1 #(redis/get 1))`. So, I can only assume I still don't get your requirements (at all). Could you please extend your question with an example of "a lot of boilerplate"?

Comment: I thought about syntax-quoting the `def`s, but not about defining a `statements` macro... This seems a good compromise for what I want to do. Thanks.

But if my use-case isn't terribly unusual, do you think it could be useful to have such helper functions integrated/submitted to carmine upstream?